# Generating 1024 bits of RSA private key using OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, cryptography, rsa, private-key

I am currently trying to generate RSA private key using these commands. I tried with both these commands.

1. openssl genrsa 1024 > key.pri
2. openssl genpkey -algorithm rsa -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:1024 -out key.pri

I get a private key from this output in base64 format. However I am interested in hex values and use the command "cat key.pri | xxd -p" to convert it to hex. When I do this, I get a key beyond 1024 bits, somewhere around 960 bytes.

How do I get a 1024 bit hex version of the private key?

I tried both the commands mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The key is a PKCS#1 private key in an ASN.1 object encoded in PEM format. You need to decode the PEM wrapper and then parse the ASN.1 wrapper to extract the PKCS#1 key. You can do that with this command:

> openssl ans1parse -inform pem -in key.pri

The last line of your output will be a hex dump of the key. Note that this still contains the modulus, public exponent, both primes, and so on. This is encoded in PKCS#1 format.

You can parse that further with:

> openssl asn1parse -in key.pri -inform pem | grep HEX | cut -f 4 -d ":" | xxd -r -p | openssl asn1parse -inform der

This extracts the private key in PKCS#1 format and then converts it to raw binary and parses it. You will see a sequence of nine integers that contain the following values in the following order:

1. PKCS#1 version (should be zero)
2. Modulus (n)
3. Public exponent (e)
4. Private exponent (d)
5. Prime 1 (p)
6. Prime 2 (q)
7. Exponent 1 (d mod [p-1] or dp)
8. Exponent 2 (d mod [q-1] or dq)
9. Coefficient (~q mod p or qinv)

Comment: I understand that we get the ASN1 format of the key using the command, but I am concerned about which 1024 bits to use in my application.

Comment: What format does your application want an RSA private key in? If PKCS#1, it's the output of the first command I showed. If you just want the modulus, it's the second number in the output of the second command. [This link](https://medium.com/@bn121rajesh/understanding-rsa-public-key-70d900b1033c) may be helpful.

Comment: My application only processes a 1024 bit hex format.

Comment: Okay, but *what* is that format? Is it the modulus in big-endian byte order?

Comment: I am not sure if its modulus, in the sample code they have used a 1024 bits hex data. The value is in little-endian byte order.

Comment: I did a bit of reading and understood that openssl does not give out the raw value of the key and only gives the components. How can I convert these components into raw value, as this is what my application supports.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "raw value". Do you need just the modulus? Do you need the private exponent?

Comment: so, the private key is made of components such as exponent and modulus. OpenSSL gives us the component instead of giving us the final private key to make it secure by not giving out the private key. We have to derive the private key from modulus and private key using tools.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "final private key". The private key is made up of components. Those components are the final private key. While not all the components are necessary, providing additional components (such as the ones needed to use the [Chinese remainder theorem speedup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm)) doesn't make things any more secure.

Comment: The components are not the private key. Do you mean to say that the private key is "modulus + private expoent" ?

Comment: @basangouda46 What do you think the difference is between "all the components of a private key" and "the private key"? The private key is all the components of a private key in some kind of defined format.